# HDMI Audio device no longer appears as playback device

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi

After a windows update connectiong my television to my notebook with an HDMI cable does not reproduce sounds as it was always doing. The sounds now come only from the notebook speakers.

Looking into the playback devices there isn't any HDMI entry but only "Speakers - Realteck high definition audio" (show disconnected devices and disable devices are checked).

It's not a cable problem, I checked. So what should be the procedure to make it work again? Reinstall all the drivers?

Nvidia graphic drivers are up to date.